# Setting up SAML SSO on Azure for a SP that strictly only takes email address mapping. Can I parse ObjectID so my users can use their ObjectID to login

Tags: single-sign-on, saml

Setting up SAML SSO on Azure for a SP that strictly only takes email address mapping. Can I parse ObjectID so my users can use their ObjectID to login?

Company policy dictates that our users use ObjectID to login, SP policy is to only map email address.